# Texture atlasing in Unity

Tags: unity, textures, rendering, uv-mapping, texture-atlas

I'm researching new ways to optimize games for better performance. Currently I am working on texture atlasing, which is giving me a hard time. I made the atlas using `Texture2D.PackTextures` and saved the offset and height and width values to a text file.

Now when I insert the values to a material the texture is shown correctly, but since batching requires that the same material is used - how I can I use the same material with different offsets?

[image]

Picture: All the cubes use the same texture. Only the two on the right batch as they use the same material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have 3 options:

1. Change UVs to point directly to the object on the texture atlas (in effect having N:N meshes:textures)
2. Create a seperate material per texture
3. If you change tiling via script it should work on the same material (although it might just be creating a clone of the current material)

P.S.
I haven't read the whole post but it seems to be discussing your question:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/276212/what-is-the-simple-way-of-applying-texture-atlas-t.html

Comment: Pointing UVs directly to the texture atlas on a modeling software did the trick, but changing the material coordinates in a script just created another instance of that material(no batching).